# android startActivityForResult streetview get data

Tags: android, google-street-view

How can I get result from streetview?
Such as Lat, Lng, Pitch, heading, FOV, Zoom...etc..

I want to make an activity, click button "walk" to open a streetview. The user walk to somewhere location, save it.

I try to use `startActivityForResult` to streetview, but I can't select the location. It just opened a streetview for view only.

```
Intent streetView = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll="+ objLatitude+","+objLongitude+"&cbp=1,99.56,,1,-5.27&mz=21"));
startActivityForResult(streetView,10);
```

Any idea or any other method can do that?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll=" + (float)aGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1000000 + "," + (float)aGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()/1000000 +"&cbp=1,180,,0,1.0")); 
startActivity(myIntent);
```